# Emberjs-1.0.0-rc.6 unable to filter controller content to return values for a particular property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I have CalendarController that uses the needs api to access AppointmentController, with the intent of filtering the content AppointmentController and return only **event.start**. But I have tried **filter()** and **forEach()** and it always returns all the different properties instead of only all the available timings for **event.start**. When I use **map()**, it gives map back only the **event.start** values as I want in the console but then handlbars fails to display anything.

```
u = App.__container__.lookup("controller:appointments");

y = u.get('content');

y.map(function(appointee) { return appointee.get('event.start') });
```

which returns:

```
[Thu Jul 18 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), Thu Jul 25 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), Thu Jul 25 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)]
```

The **[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8YxY/1/)** for when we use **map()** and calendars template displays nothing.  This **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8YxY/)** USES **FILTER()** and calendar template displays the content but instead of just event.start, it returns every of its content and filters nothing.

```
 App.AppointmentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ });
```

Calendarscontroller **todayEvent** property using **filter()**:

```
 App.CalendarController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: ['appointments'],

   todayEvent: function(){
      var _self = this;
      var appoint = _self.get('controllers.appointments');

      var appCont = appoint.get('content');

      return appCont.filter(function(appointee) {
         return appointee.get('event.start');
      });
  }.property()

});
```

Note I added {{name}} property to demonstrate that what is returned by the **todayEvent property** is not filtering by **event.start** but rather than returning only 'event.start', it is returning all the properties.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='calendar'>

    <h1> from todayEvent</h1>
     {{#each todayEvent}}
        {{name}}<br/>
         {{event.start}}<br/>
     {{/each}}
```

Router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('events');    
  this.resource('appointments');
  this.route('calendar', {path: '/cal'});
});
```

**ember-model is used:**:

```
App.Appointment = Ember.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.attr(),
  event : Ember.belongsTo('App.Event', {key: 'event_id'})
```

});

```
App.Event = Ember.Model.extend( {
  title: Ember.attr(),
  start: Ember.attr(Date),
  end: Ember.attr(Date),
  allDay: Ember.attr(Boolean),
  appointments: Ember.hasMany('App.Appointment',  {key:  'appointment_ids'})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter method just returns the enumerables for which the passed function evaluates true. You can use the map method as you did. Your code

```
y.map(function(appointee) { return appointee.get('event.start') });
```

returns an array of start date as you expected. The typo was in your calender hbs.

```
   {{#each todayEvent}}
     {{this}}
   {{/each}}
```

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8YxY/2/)

Comment: I see some constraints in your appointments controller. Without visiting appointments route, its content is never setup. Visiting calender route without the content of appointments controller will just result empty array. I'm not aware of your code structure too

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Beside pre-loading my appointments model, do you know another way to avoid that constraint. 2ndly, may be I will ask another question, because the code I pasted here is the shortened version of what I wanted to do. which is loop through the content and filter by date. **todayEvent: function(){var _self = this; var appoint = _self.get('controllers.appointments'); var appCont = appoint.get('content');  return appCont.map(function(appointee) {return (moment(appointee.get('event.start')).unix() == moment(_self.get('date')).unix());});}.property('date')**

Comment: If tried it as a controller method it will work see **App.EventsController and the todayEvent method there** but as a controller property in App.CalendarController, as shown in my earlier question, it doesn't list the evets for a particular date but just returns true or false. here is the **jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ya6rg/3/**. Pls do yo know why?

Comment: You are falling in the same trap again. If you want to return a enumerable based on a condition, you can go up with the filter method. MeanWhile you can also use the .map method by returning if the condition is met. Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ya6rg/4/ ... You should also use getters to access the ember KVO property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794581/emberjs-1-0-0-rc-6-using-enumerable-to-list-events-occurring-on-a-particular-dat